# XSS Vulnerability Reproduction

Tags: xss

I have a Qualys web application scan report that says I have a XSS vulnerability. It explains this was detected by requesting a malicious payload and evaluating the response.

When I make the same request, I'm getting a different response that doesn't appear vulnerable.

The request: `https://my.site/asection/Some%20Param?"><qss>=`

Response the scanner gets:

```
<a href="/asection/index.cfm?param=A Different Param&"><qss>=" class="current">
```

Response I get:

```
 <a href="/asection/index.cfm?param=Some Param&%22%3E%3Cqss%3E=" class="current">
```

Why can't I duplicate the scanner's results? What do I need to do to get a clean scan?

EDIT: Thanks for the advice, all. I'm afraid I'm still stumped here. I've tried making the request from a browser, from python via requests and from wget with the same results (shown above). The headers I'm seeing from Qualys:
[image]

```
GET https://my.site/asection/Some%20%20Param?"><qss>=
Referer: http://my.site/
Cookie: JSESSIONID=48BBDB43C2DAF217644045004E3AF105.cfusion; CFTOKEN=4e91b60205baf756-E6723476-DAFC-BF6E-EB44114CE65CBF13; CFID=7001629;
Host: my.site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4
Accept: */*
```

and the headers I'm seeing with wget (via `wget -d "https://my.site/asection/Some%20Param?\"><qss>="`

```
GET /asection/Some%20Param?%3E%3Cqss%3E=%0A HTTP/1.1                                                            
Referer: http://my.site/
Cookie: JSESSIONID=48BBDB43C2DAF217644045004E3AF105.cfusion; CFTOKEN=4e91b60205baf756-E6723476-DAFC-BF6E-EB44114CE65CBF13; CFID=7001629;   
Host: my.site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4                                                                                                                
Accept: */*                                                                                                             
Accept-Encoding: identity                                                                                               
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I've re-run the scan and it still detects the vulnerability. I've reviewed [Why isn't this XSS working?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206018/why-isnt-this-xss-working). Are all of my requests getting returned URL Encoded? Is there a tool (or a flag in wget/requests) that will let me suppress this to see the raw response or the decoded response?

Comment: Do you use the same headers as Qualys scanner do? Make sure You are reproducing **full HTTP request**, not just the URL one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't this XSS working?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206018/why-isnt-this-xss-working) It's not an exact duplicate, but I'm quite sure the answer applies to your case too.

Comment: How are you sending such request? Maybe with a browser that contains an anti-XSS?

Comment: Try the URL via cURL or wget in a terminal of whatever OS you are using - the response looks the same except that your browser is encoding your request

Answer (score 1):

Your header is of course showing it in URI encoding because it's a URI.  You need to look at the actual body - your report stated it was in an `a` tag, so look for that `a` tag.  Pass your output through `grep` and it should fall out.  You won't see it in a `GET` because that is the data you are sending to the server (or directly what the server is receiving, either way)

Comment: Could you clarify how to "look at the actual body." I was under the impression that the methods I was using (browser, wget, python requests) were displaying the response body (a snippet of which I included in the "Response I get" section of the post.) I only put the headers into my post to demonstrate if the headers on my requests were comparable to the headers in the scanner's request.

Comment: Hmmmm, I did mean the response body, from curl/wget etc. Not sure now, complete guess but maybe something with the -d flag makes is altering it - you do show the request headers directly from the terminal, right? How does qualys display theirs?

Comment: updated post with a picture of the qualys headers. The results of wget -d and wget both have the same response:  <a href="/asection/index.cfm?param=Some Param&%22%3E%3Cqss%3E=" class="current">

Comment: It could be how they process their info then, it might be a bug in how it's reported - best off reaching out to Qualys perhaps